# How to read a .txt file in JAVA and construct a graph based on that?

Tags: java, swing, graph-theory

I want my program to read a .txt file and construct a graph based on that. For example, if it is written (3,5) in file it should output a graph connecting the 3rd and 5th nodes.

What I have at this moment is the code of file reader which reads a file and stores in a string list line my line and prints for ex. the first line(although I'm not sure do I really need that). I don't know how to continue. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Visualization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my/Path/Here"));
        String str;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(str);
        }

        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(stringArr[1]);
    }
}
```

P.S I also have tried to create my own graph using JUNG API. Problem is that I gave all the input by hand, and I want my program to read it from a .txt file. Here is the code:

```
   import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.*;  
   import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;   
   import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;   
   import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;   
   import java.awt.*;   
   import javax.swing.JFrame;   
   public class GraphVis {   
   Graph<Integer, String> g;



public GraphVis() {

    g = new SparseMultigraph<Integer, String>();

    g.addVertex((Integer) 1);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 2);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 3);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 4);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 5);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 6);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 7);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 8);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 9);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 10);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 11);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 12);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 13);
    g.addVertex((Integer) 14);

    g.addEdge("1", 1,2);
    g.addEdge("2", 2, 6);
    g.addEdge("3", 2, 6);
    g.addEdge("4", 2, 7);
    g.addEdge("5", 2, 7);
    g.addEdge("6", 2,12);
    g.addEdge("7", 2,3);
    g.addEdge("8", 2,3);
    g.addEdge("9", 3,4);
    g.addEdge("10", 3,4);
    g.addEdge("11", 3,6);
    g.addEdge("12", 3,6);
    g.addEdge("13", 3,7);
    g.addEdge("14", 3,7);
    g.addEdge("15", 3,12);
    g.addEdge("16", 4,5);
    g.addEdge("17", 4,13);
    g.addEdge("18", 4,13);
    g.addEdge("19", 4,8);
    g.addEdge("20", 4,12);
    g.addEdge("21", 4,12);
    g.addEdge("22", 4,7);
    g.addEdge("23", 4,7);
    g.addEdge("24", 4,6);
    g.addEdge("25", 4,6);
    g.addEdge("26", 5,12);
    g.addEdge("27", 5,11);
    g.addEdge("28", 5,11);
    g.addEdge("29", 5,13);
    g.addEdge("30", 5,8);
    g.addEdge("31", 5,8);
    g.addEdge("32", 5,9);
    g.addEdge("33", 5,9);
    g.addEdge("34", 5,9);
    g.addEdge("35", 5,14);
    g.addEdge("36", 5,14);
    g.addEdge("37", 5,10);
    g.addEdge("38", 5,10);
    g.addEdge("39", 6,12);
    g.addEdge("40", 6,12);
    g.addEdge("41", 6,12);
    g.addEdge("42", 6,7);
    g.addEdge("43", 6,7);
   }   


public static void main(String[] args) {    
    GraphVis sgv = new GraphVis();   
    Layout<Integer, String> layout = new CircleLayout(sgv.g);    
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));   
VisualizationViewer<Integer,String> vv = new          
VisualizationViewer<Integer,String>(layout);     
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,750));     
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph View ");     
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    frame.getContentPane().add(vv);    
    frame.pack();    
    frame.setVisible(true);    
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you have a good start. You need to find an API to generate graphs with the technology you want. By the way, this is off-topic to ask for API or other off-site resource

Comment: I think i'm going to use JUNG API. I was able to create a particular graph with, but I don't know how to convert my code such that it takes vertex and edge information from a file.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't try and show what you have. I don't know the API, I don't see any code about GUI so I don't know what you are trying to achievement and how. See [ask]

Comment: My apologies. Now I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have options! If you want to use the api directly, JUNG has a [reader for the GraphML format](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) already available for you, just use the load method. If you're flexible about your graph format, you could try using [Gephi](https://github.com/gephi/gephi), which has an export format to GraphML.

If you're not so flexible about how the text format is, you can still iterate through the graph. The part that you're stuck on is parsing the `String`. Once you've extracted the two vertices of an edge, add them if they aren't already part of the graph, and then add their edge. Assuming a well-formed file:

```
Pattern vertexer = Pattern.compile("\\((.*),(.*)\\)");
Integer counter = 1;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher extractor = vertexer.matcher(str);
    Integer source = extractor.group(1);
    Integer target = extractor.group(2);
    g.addVertex(source);
    g.addVertex(target);
    g.addEdge(counter.toString(), source, target);
    counter++;
}
```

Note: it's okay to add the source and target vertex. The JUNG API guarantees that the code will run and not make duplicate vertices. The method call just returns false.